# Apache Kafka (CVE-2023-25194)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm currently using Spring Boot 2.4.x in my service, and I've separately upgraded the versions of spring-kafka and kafka-client to 2.9.10 and 3.4.0, respectively. The reason for this upgrade is to address the following security vulnerability: https://developer.aliyun.com/article/1245287

After the upgrade, the service starts up and runs as normal. However, I'm unsure whether upgrading spring-kafka alone, while keeping the Spring Boot version at 2.4.5, could introduce other issues. To resolve this security vulnerability, is it feasible to directly upgrade spring-kafka and kafka-client without upgrading Spring Boot?

To resolve this security vulnerability, is it feasible to directly upgrade spring-kafka and kafka-client without upgrading Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, such an action is OK. However you still need to look into upgrading Spring Boot to the latest supported. The `2.4.x` generation is out of support for a while: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

Comment: You should definitely upgrade to a supported Boot version, but please be aware that that CVE relates only to Kafka Connect, which is not used by Spring. You only need to be concerned if you are actually using Connect in your application.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the listed CVE is related to Kafka Connect API, which is not a dependency of `spring-kafka` or `kafka-clients`, therefore you would be unaffected by that one in particular, but that doesn't mean there aren't other vulnerabilities that have been addressed since the Spring-Kafka / kafka-clients version you do have